# Design API for Create Pivot in Excel Using Java

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, pivot-table, smartxls

I am Java Developer and I want to design Java API for creating a Pivot Table in Excel. However, I am stuck how would I create one? Does anybody have an idea about how to design Java API for creating a Pivot Table in Excel. I am familiar with POI, SmartXLS APIs, but POI doesn't provide any method for creating Pivot Table in Excel and SmartXLS is costs money. So please help.

Answer (score 1):

You can user [ZK Pivottable](http://www.zkoss.org/product/zkpivottable) for pivot table related development. ZK is an opensource framework take a look at [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZK_Framework)

Comment: Please note my updated answer. ZK is an opensource framework.